# Pandas read sql integer became float

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, int

I met a problem that when I use pandas to read Mysql table, some columns (see 'to_nlc') used to be integer became a float number (automatically add .0 after that).
Can anyone figure it out? Or some guessings? Thanks very much!

[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem is your data contains `NaN` values, so `int` is automatically cast to `float`.

I think you can check [NA type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions):

> When introducing NAs into an existing Series or DataFrame via reindex or some other means, boolean and integer types will be promoted to a different dtype in order to store the NAs. These are summarized by this table:

```
Typeclass   Promotion dtype for storing NAs
floating    no change
object      no change
integer     cast to float64
boolean     cast to object
```

> While this may seem like a heavy trade-off, in practice I have found very few cases where this is an issue in practice. Some explanation for the motivation here in the next section.

Comment: how can this be avoided? The integer are used as identifiers so that casting to float causes precision errors

Comment: @HananShteingart - is possible replace `NaN` to `0` ? like `df['colname'] = df['colname'].fillna().astype(int)` or `df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)` ?

Comment: I already get it as float from the SQL. What I did is to cast the column to a string in the sql query: e.g. CAST(bigint_column AS VARCHAR) so I get it as a string in the dataframe. I didn't mind that it's not numeric anymore because the column represents an ID anyway.

Comment: Is there an update for this answer? I've seen https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: @MartinThoma - Honestly no idea, if use `integer na` and raise error then not.

Answer (score 1):

As already said the problem is that pandas' integer can not handle NULL/NA value.

You can replace read_sql_table with read_sql and convert NULL to some integer value (for example 0 or -1, something which has NULL sense in your setting):

```py
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT col1, col2, IFNULL(col3, 0) FROM table", engine)
```

Here col3 can be NULL in mysql, ifnull will return 0 if it is NULL or col3 value otherwise.

Or same thing with little function helper:

```py
def read_sql_table_with_nullcast(table_name, engine, null_cast={}):
    """
    table_name - table name
    engine - sql engine
    null_cast - dictionary of columns to replace NULL:
           column name as key value to replace with as value.
           for example {'col3':0} will set all NULL in col3 to 0
    """
    import pandas
    cols = pandas.read_sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " + table_name, engine)
    cols_call = [c if c not in null_cast else "ifnull(%s,%d) as %s"%(c,null_cast[c],c) for c in cols['Field']]
    sel = ",".join(cols_call)
    return pandas.read_sql("SELECT " + sel + " FROM " + table_name, engine)

read_sql_table_with_nullcast("table", engine, {'col3':0})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters: coerce_float=False

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn, coerce_float=False)

coerce_floatbool, default True
Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point, useful for SQL result sets.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to exclude `NULL` values in the `WHERE` clause of your SQL query, if you're not expecting them and they correspond to unusable rows.

So it won't be suitable in all circumstances, but is a clean and simple option when it does apply.