# Pd.read_sql add zero to int number from table sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter, read-sql

I'm wondering why pandas.read_sql add .zero at the end of my data please ?
In SQL Server, the data are number indicated like int.

[image]

Someone knows why please?

And when I look type of data, it's indicated like float64.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796916/pandas-read-sql-integer-became-float), this happens because your data might contains `NaN` values, so in order to handle this, `int` data type is automatically converted to `float`.

When introducing NAs into an existing Series or DataFrame via reindex or some other means, `boolean` and integer types will be promoted to a different dtype in order to store the NAs. These are summarized by this table:

```
Typeclass   Promotion dtype for storing NAs
floating    no change
object      no change
integer     cast to float64
boolean     cast to object
```