# How to resolve if `pandas.read.sql()` converts `bigint` to `float64` automatically?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, types, read-sql

I have a field `ID`, in MySQL Workbench it's `Bigint(20)` type, and if I query in the workbench, it looks like this:

```
ID
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
...
```

If I use `pandas.read_sql()` then print out this column, it looks like this:

```
ID
1.111111e+09
2.222222e+09
3.333333e+09
...
```

and by checking `df.dtypes`, this columns is `float64` type,
if I try to convert it to `str` by using: `df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype('str')`, this column will become like this:

```
ID
1111111111.0
2222222222.0
3333333333.0
```

I'm confused... I thought the `Bigint(20)` after `read_sql()` will become `int64`, but why here it becomes `float64`, is there a way I can just converted it to `int64` or `str` and it looks like `1111111111` (without the float `.0`?)

I also tried `df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype('int64')`, but it gave me error `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Can someone help please... Thanks.

Comment: Does the `ID` column happen to have `NULL` values?

Comment: ID has null values, per the `ValueError`. Float is used instead of `int` because `int` doesn't support null values. Consider, if you really want integers, using panda's `'Int64'` dtype extension. Cf https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html.

Comment: what @ifly6 said, and also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796916/pandas-read-sql-integer-became-float

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise this is because of the NULL values, I used `SELECT Cast(ID as char) AS ID,` instead of `SELECT ID` in my query seems resolved the issue, is there any downside?

Comment: oh I found out there's only one NULL value, so if I add a condition in the query to exclude it, seems like this column is converted to `int64` now.